# while delete/Update a structure value in vector getting the compilation error?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, mfc

I have insert the structure value in vector and now I want to delete/update the particular structure.

I have tried like:
Define the structure

```
struct _Data
{
    std::string sPath;
    unsigned short *id;
    UINT nValue;

};
```

Define a vector

```
vector<struct _Data> vDATA;
```

Now insert the value in vector in main method.

```
struct _Data Record;
vDATA.push_back(Record);
```

I have insert the n number value. Now I am trying to get the id from the structure one by one from the vector and update with different id.
I have tried as :

```
for(int i = 0; i< vDATA.size(); i++)
{
    Record = vDATA[i];
    std::string sTempPath = Record.sPath;
    UINT nTemp = Record.nValue ;
    std::wstring sTemp = Record.id;
```

Now update the value of ID:

```
Record.id = <different value>
vDATA.erase(i);
vDATA.push_back(Record);
```

While compilation it is generating the error as  'struct *Data **_thiscall std::vector >::erase(struct _Data *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'struct _Data

Any suggestion, where I did mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase in a vector takes an **iterator** not an index. This change should do the job:

```
vDATA.erase(vDATA.begin() + i);
```

The code above takes an iterator to the element with index `i` in the vector and then calls erase for it.

Answer (score 1):

The erase method in the vector does not take the integer as the parameter. It takes the iterator as the parameter.

Refer [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) for more details.